# c++ weird struct and bitset error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, struct, bitset

I have this inside my private class declarations

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;
    template <typename Key, typename T>
    class A{
    //....
    private:
        static const unsigned int HSIZE = 32;
        struct Bucket {
            Key key;
            T value;
            bitset<HSIZE> jumpMap;
        };
    //....
    };
```

Gives the following errors:

```
Error   1   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed
Error   2   error C2059: syntax error : '<'
Error   3   error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

And when i remove the bitset line, it gives me no errors. What am i doing wrong?

EDIT: Added more relevant lines

Comment: Is this the real code? Because I don't see what is `Key`, `T`, `HMAX` - are they defined?

Comment: Let me add the full class delcaration

Comment: No need to add the full class definition, especially if it's long. Just the things, I'm asking for :) Also, have you included the bitset header and included namespace std?

Comment: what you need is templates http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_%28programming%29

Comment: Now would you be so gentle to add the template instantiation that is triggering such error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you included the bitset header? I think you have missed it?

Comment: jesus wth? i included it on stdfax.h but it doesnt work. But if i include it in the header itself, it works. Can somebody explain why is this?

Comment: Why you think, that `stdfax` will include all headers for you :)

Comment: See this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676385/stdafx-h-when-do-i-need-it

Comment: I thought the idea of stdfax is to include all your headers there, then just include stdfax to have all of them on one call

Comment: Yep, I've got it, that's why I posted the link above :) No problems, I'm glad, that I helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Should HMAX be HSIZE instead? Otherwise make sure you include < bitset >, and that the name is in scope. You probably have a using namespace std in your code, since you don't qualify it with std::. But my bet goes to HMAX <-> HSIZE.